# Masonry: topLayoutGuide/bottomLayoutGuide cause crash in iOS9

Tags: autolayout, ios9, masonry

Masonry: topLayoutGuide/bottomLayoutGuide cause crash in iOS9

Code in demo:

```
[topView makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    UIView *topLayoutGuide = (id)self.topLayoutGuide;

    // topLayoutGuide cause exception
    make.top.equalTo(topLayoutGuide.mas_bottom);

    make.left.equalTo(self.view);
    make.right.equalTo(self.view);
    make.height.equalTo(@40);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `self.mas_topLayoutGuide` because `self.topLayoutGuide` is not a UIView object.

```
[topView makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

    make.top.equalTo(self.mas_topLayoutGuide);

    make.left.equalTo(self.view);
    make.right.equalTo(self.view);
    make.height.equalTo(@40);
}]
```